# Force Visible Property to Apply During Button Click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to hide a button and replace it with a label until a query finishes to populate a grid view. My button .aspx page looks like so:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSelect" HorizontalAlign="Center" >
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Please Select an Item" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlItems" AutoPostBack="true" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnItemSubmit" Text="Submit" /> <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblItemSubmit" Text="Please Wait" Visible="false" />
</asp:Panel>
```

and here is the .aspx.vb code behind that is handling execution:

```
Protected Sub btnItemSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnItemSubmit.Click

        btnItemSubmit.Visible = False
        lblItemSubmit.Visible = True

        oracleSql()

        btnItemSubmit.Visible = True
        lblItemSubmit.Visible = False

End Sub
```

My problem is that the properties don't apply until after the sub finishes execution, at which point no changes are visibly made because the properties immediately went back to how they were originally. Is there a way to get these properties to apply asynchronously?

Edit:
Here is `Page_Load`

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Page.IsPostBack Then
            'was causing query to reload on button click and default back to first item on list, this way allows it to retain whichever item was selected
            'setting postback = false on ddl did not resolve the issue either
        Else
            Dim oracleConn As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
            oracleConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnString").ConnectionString

            Dim sql As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand

            sql.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            sql.CommandText = "select * from Items order by 1"

            sql.Connection = oracleConn

            Dim dataAdapter As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.DataAdapter(sql)
            Dim dataSet As New DataSet

            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)

            ddlItems.DataSource = dataSet
            ddlItems.DataTextField = "item_name"
            ddlItems.DataValueField = "item_id"

            ddlItems.DataBind()
        End If
End Sub
```

oracleSql() is similar to this, just binding to a gridview instead of a ddl.

Comment: Show your ````Page_Load```` event.  Are you binding data in this event, or setting property values?

Comment: Ah, looks like you already solved the issue I thought you might have (re-binding grid/properties of PostBack).

Comment: Now that I have had a better look, I think you should use Ajax .  You could disable the buttons/elements during the processing, and then on success you'd re-enable them.  I really hate having to deal with Async via code-behind....you'd have to implement UpdatePanels I'd believe.

Comment: I suppose maybe you could do some JS hack.  Have an OnClientClick event that uses JS to disable the elements you want, and then re-enable them in code-behind or JS after you've reloaded the page (may have to use Page.ClientScriptManager to register a script on PostBack).  Just a thought.

Comment: JohnPete22 is right. There are plenty of nice examples of how to do this with Ajax, jQuery, etc.  It means some code-refactoring, but considering the nature of ASPX (server-side execution, with a client-side UI), there aren't many options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on recommendations from JohnPete22, I ended up creating a simple Javascript function to handle this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function hideShowBtn() { document.getElementById('btnItemSubmit').style.visibility = 'hidden'; };
</script>
```

I then added it to the `OnClientClick` property of my button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnItemSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="hideShowBtn()" />
```

The button would disappear when clicked and return after `PostBack`.